# Kernel Firmware for Radeon

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, firmware, ati

I'm building LFS. I was trying to enable `Ati radeon` drivers in the kernel, but it didn't seem to work, so I did a little Googling and found that the there is something called `firmware` which the kernel needs in order to work with the H/W. I checked my `dmesg` and found that my kernel tries to load the file `radeon/OLAND_pfp.bin` from `lib/firmware/radeon` which unfortunately is not present.

I checked my other distros and they all have it. I know that when I run `make modules_install` the modules and firmware are copied into the required directories, but I want to know how to get this `firmware`. Also if I plan to run this LFS on other systems with different H/W, how can I get the maximum driver support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All firmware which isn't distributable under the GPL-2 isn't provided within the kernel, but is available separately in the [linux-firmware](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git) project. You'll find `OLAND_pfp.bin` there; you can clone the repository and run `make install` as `root`, which will install all the firmware in appropriate sub-directories of `/lib/firmware`.

Comment: wow, thanks bro, I'll try it tonight! thanks again.

Comment: Another thing you said, i have to `make install` them. Can we also add them to the kernel source and compile them along with it?

Comment: I don't think so, it's really a separate project, and its lifecycle isn't the same as the kernel's (there isn't a new version of `linux-firmware` every time a new kernel is released). There's nothing to compile in the firmware anyway; it's all just binaries which get copied to the correct location. Take a look at `Makefile`, you'll see it doesn't do much at all...